# javascript function in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, forms, onsubmit

I have jsp page -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <legend>Create new customer</legend>
    <script Language="JavaScript">
        function checkForm() {

            alert("YOU ARE IN checkForm FUNCTION !");
            return (false);
        }
    </script>
    <form action="CreateCustomerServlet" method="GET" onsubmit="checkForm">
        // form fields ... 
        <input type="submit" value="Create customer" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run on server this page and press on the `submit` button I see that it ignore `checkForm` and don't enter him , and directly go to `CreateCustomerServlet` .

My goals is that when press on `submit` it go to `checkForm` and if `checkForm` returns `true` only then it will go to `CreateCustomerServlet`  . what I have to change in order to get this goal ?

Comment: I wanted to know.. I have written same code in jsp but in welcome.jsp... but it's not working there, can you please make me know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
onsubmit="return checkForm();"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
onsubmit="checkForm"
```

By

```
onsubmit="return checkForm();"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
onsubmit="return checkForm();"
```

because only when `false` is returned from `onSubmit` will it be stopped , or else it will continue submitting the form.