# javascript call from JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I want to call javascript function but instead of calling javascript function it is redirecting to another JSP page by accessing SERVLET.
I found a help from a link, He has also used same process as I am doing.

Link which I found: [javascript function in jsp page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792682/javascript-function-in-jsp-page)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callCommom() {
            alert("Method Called");
            return (false);
        }
    </script>
    <form action="Common" method="post" onsubmit="return callCommon()">
        <table align="center" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Assignment</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table align="center" border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Assignment Number</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="assnName" id="assnname">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="button" name="btnClear"
                                id="clearButton" value="Clear"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest me ... I need your help.

Comment: Are you trying to validate the form in javascript before submitting to the servlet or do you actually not want to submit to the servlet at all?

Comment: you can use onclick on submit button call same function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *typo* error. Must be:

```html
<form action="Common" method="post" onsubmit="return callCommom()">
                                                              ^
```

Or:

```js
function callCommon() {
                  ^
```

Comment: OMG!! Thank you so much... I was breaking my head, But I didn't noticed it. :)

Comment: You're welcome. — Do not worry. These things happen. It was a pleasure to help. :)